# How to make buttons work from second window in my QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis-2, qt-designer, pyqt4

I'm trying to develop a QGIS plugin. I already created a second window. In that second window, there are several buttons that I need them to work. I can't say I'm a programmer that's why I don't really know what should I add to my main plugin code?

This is the part of the code I included in my main plugin code to show a second window:

```py
def secondscr(self):
    #code the 2nd screen here
    self.Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.ui = Ui_Form()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.Form)
    self.Form.show()
    self.Form.comboBox
```

And then in the run def: I added this line of code

```
self.dlg.pb_1.clicked.connect(self.secondscr)
```

Now, I have a comboBox in my second window.
I used this code in my run def:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
self.dlg.comboBox.addItems([layer.name() for layer in layers])
```

The problem is that my main plugin code doesn't know what is comboBox (since it only exists in my second window not in my main window).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.